# Feign.Builder "target values must be absolute" error: how to call docker container with absolute url?

Tags: docker, openfeign

I have several microservices communicating each other with `OpenFeign`. Each one is a submodule of a project(call it "parent"), with its own docker container.

OK. So, when I want to build a client with `feign.builder().target()` method, an error occurs claiming that "target values must be absolute". I checked the source code, and it means (`feign.RequestTemplate.target(RequestTemplate.java:447)`):

```java
  public static boolean isAbsolute(String uri) {
    return uri != null && !uri.isEmpty() && uri.startsWith("http");
  }
```

Here comes the question: the url of other services are like:

```
another-service:8080/check
```

In local tests, this is not a problem, because the profile `local` has `http://localhost:8080` and so on. But in an end-to-end test this cannot bypass the absolute check.

So, what to do now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just added `http://` before the service name and this is fixed.

Looks like when creating containers needing to communicate with each other, docker does two things:

- creating a network composed by these containers, and assign IP for each. In my case, the IP are like `172.26.0.2`, not as `localhost` or `192.168.xx.xx`.
- acting as a DNS server: it map IP to domains same as service name in `docker-compose.yml`. Like, in `docker-compose.yml` I have `service-A`, in the network of docker, I can `docker exec -it bash` to run shell and `curl http://service-A:8080` to visit it.

Note that I used inner ports, not "outer" ports. For example, if service-A has ports config like:

```
ports:
  - "8083:8080"
```

Inside the network(`curl` from other containers) we use 8080, but from "outside"(from host, using Postman) we use 8083.

PS:

I used `uname -a` to check the dist of container is Debian and then I `apt update && apt install curl` to install `curl` executable.

Answer (score 1):

For me the URL wasn't being loaded from properties due to this small error:

```
@Value("${${my.url}})
String myUrl
```

It should be:

```
@Value("${my.url})
String myUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `http` or `https` before your base url` and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can using Ip of the computer/laptop idk the reason but it fixed the issue you can check yours with **ipconfig** in terminal

Answer (score 0):

In case someone shows up with the same issue, I fixed this by removing quotes from around the URL being passed.  I didn't notice it was a problem until I brought up the value in the debugger and spotted the extra set of quotes, thus violating startsWith("http").